# Capture and Display Image

Tags: java, android, webview, android-camera, android-camera-intent

So I'm trying to capture a photo with the help of built-in camera intent and display it in my `WebView`.

Here's the code I've written:

centCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
         count++;
        String file = dir+count+".jpg";
        File newfile = new File(file);
        try {
            newfile.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {}       

        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newfile);

        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);             
    }
});
```

It captures the image,names it `count` and saves it in `dir`. Simple. Now the hard part is that I can't display this in the `WebView`.

The code for this should be:

```
wv1.loadUrl(file)
```

The problem's that I don't know where to put that line. For instance, if it's placed in `onClick()`, WebView will display "The webpage at X might be temporarily down..."

Everybody's answering similar questions with this piece of code:

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == Globals.REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            this.onPhotoTaken();
        }
    }
}
```

Adding it doesn't work for me though - I get a lot of errors, that can't be simply fixed by adding imports.

[image]

```
Globals cannot be resolved to a variable

RESULT_OK cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Comment: "Everybody's answering similar questions with this piece of code" -- that's because that's the correct answer, other than fixing the first `if` to refer to your own result code. "I get a lot of errors" -- edit your question and explain, **completely**, what these errors are, and what *your* code is that is triggering these errors.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Updated the question

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities):

> Sometimes you want to get a result back from an activity when it ends. For example, you may start an activity that lets the user pick a person in a list of contacts; when it ends, it returns the person that was selected. To do this, you call the `startActivityForResult(Intent, int)` version with a second integer parameter identifying the call. The result will come back through your `onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)` method.

Quoting [the documentation for `onActivityResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29), the first passed-in parameter is:

> The integer request code originally supplied to `startActivityForResult()`, allowing you to identify who this result came from.

Hence, replace `Globals.REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA` with `TAKE_PHOTO_CODE`.

With regards to `RESULT_OK`, [that is defined on `Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#RESULT_OK). `onActivityResult()` needs to be implemented on the `Activity` or `Fragment` on which you called `startActivityForResult()`. If it is implemented on a `Fragment`, replace `RESULT_OK` with `Activity.RESULT_OK`.

Comment: This explained a lot. Thank you. I still get **Webpage not available**, but I ran the test Toast, and it displayed itself right when I ticked that I want to save the image on the sd card.